# how to fix the setstate delay problem in react class component

Tags: delay, setstate

I have been stuck on the simple issue of the common React setState delay in class component.

here i upload my code for your clarification,

```
handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();`your text`
  let {StudentName,StudentEmail,StudentDOB,isName,isEmail,isDOB,isvalidAge,isvalidEmail,isSubmit} = this.state;
  if(StudentName.length===0)
{
 await this.setState({isName:false});
} else{
 await this.setState({isName:true});
}


if(StudentEmail.length===0){
await  this.setState({isEmail:false});
}
else if(StudentEmail.length>0)
{
  const emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
  if(emailPattern.test(StudentEmail))
  {`your text`
     await this.setState({isvalidEmail:true,isEmail:true});
  }
  else{
      await this.setState({isvalidEmail:false,isEmail:false});
  }
}
else{
 await this.setState({isEmail:false});
}

if(StudentDOB.length===0){
 await this.setState({isDOB:false});
}
else if(StudentDOB.length>0)
{
const now = moment();
const dob = moment(StudentDOB, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
const age = now.diff(dob, 'years');
if(age>=18)
{
await  this.setState({isvalidAge:true,isDOB:true});
}
else{
await  this.setState({isvalidAge:false,isDOB:false});
}

}
else{
await  this.setState({isDOB:true});
}
  if(isName&&isEmail&&isDOB&&isvalidAge&&isvalidEmail&&isId)
{
 await this.setState({isSubmit:true});

}
  let data = {};
  data = {
      StudentName:StudentName,
      StudentEmail:StudentEmail,
      StudentDOB:StudentDOB,
}

   try{
       if(isSubmit===true)
      {
          let result = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/post",data)
       }
      else{
           alert("Must Fill The All Field")
       }
   }catch(error) 
   {
    console.log(error);
   }
}
```

I got a problem was setstate is delaying,setstate is not update immediately.

i try another way setstate call back function that also not working.
anybody suggest me a solution